# Zip folder exclude some folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to backup my www-folder but hidden folders like .config inside www are added to the backup. I want to exclude the folder "backups" and all folders (and files) starting with a dot.

The problem is that it copies all the hidden folders like .config to the zip-file.

Current code:

```
zip -r /var/www/backups/site/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M).zip /var/www -x "*backups*" "*.*" "*/.*"
```

Comment: You didn't say why you're unhappy with your current code. Also, `"*.*"` aren't files or folders starting with a dot.

Comment: Cross-posted as AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/607791/zip-folder-exclude-some-folders

Comment: @4ae1e1 apparently forgot that, added it now.

Comment: I can't reproduce (I'm not on Ubuntu though). Can you create a simpler example directory structure, and show us exactly what goes into the zip archive?

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you.

```
zip -r --exclude=*backups* --exclude=*/.* /var/www/backups/site/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M).zip /var/www
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a linux find command with an exclude flag, then pipe it into zip.

The following command will exclude all paths under the current directory containing the keywords "backups" or files with "/." in the path and then pipe the files into zip.

```
    find . | grep -v "\(backups\|/\.\)" | xargs zip archive.zip
```